# How to Check Directory exist or not in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

To check directory exist or not ,i have used this below command

```
hdfs dfs -test -d /HDFS/Sample
```

Here Sample is a directory in HDFS.

commands says that if path is directory,it will return 0 , when i execute this command in prompt,i am unable to get 0 in command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check exit status of command. In bash you may use `echo $?`.

```
$hdfs dfs -test -d /tmp/testdir
$echo $?
1
```

Above example shows `/tmp/testdir` does not exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
[oracle@bigdatalite tmp]$ hdfs dfs -ls 
Found 12 items
drwx------   - oracle oracle          0 2018-01-09 15:06 .Trash
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2018-01-09 16:06 .sparkStaging
drwx------   - oracle oracle          0 2017-11-20 14:44 .staging
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2017-01-15 17:19 indexMetadata
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2017-01-15 17:19 jobRegistry
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2018-10-02 11:04 kevin_learning
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2017-01-15 17:19 mediademo
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2017-01-15 17:19 moviedemo
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2017-01-15 17:19 moviework
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2017-01-15 17:19 oggdemo
drwxr-xr-x   - oracle oracle          0 2017-01-15 17:19 oozie-oozi
drwxrwxrwx   - oracle oracle          0 2017-11-17 16:39 tmp
[oracle@bigdatalite tmp]$ hdfs dfs -test -d kevin_learning
[oracle@bigdatalite tmp]$ echo $?
0
[oracle@bigdatalite tmp]$ hdfs dfs -test -d kevin_learning2
[oracle@bigdatalite tmp]$ echo $?
1
[oracle@bigdatalite tmp]$
```

Comment: here is a quick example. $?: 1 means directory not existing; 0 means directory exists